# Two DomainContext or data sources with WCF RIA - Silverlight page

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, datacontext, ria

I am writting a Silverlight Business Application with WCF RIA link.

I have 2 databases on same SQL server, Public and Private.
The Public database contains a table which is mostly for public access level, like "user" table which has basic user information

The Private database contains a table which has "private" information, user bank transactions etc

I created 2 ADO.Net entity models, one each for Private and Public database and selected the tables.
I also created 2 different domain context services

On on Silverlight page, I need to get information from the tables that are across 2 databases, Private and Public as described above.

How do I achieve this? I am thinking of some kind of a wrapper that internally gets data from domain services.
Whats the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply just create two, or more domain services classes in your web application and (rebuild) they will be available in the Silverlight application.

There are a few restrictions, you can't have the same table in two different domain services classes. You can't use two domain services from two separate web applications the domain services must exist in the same web application which you chose for the WCF RIA link.

Hope this helps.
Rich